# how to override a parent class method in a subclass so that its return type is the subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, super

say class A is a parent of B.

```
class A {
    A foo() {
        return new A();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    B foo() {
        return super.foo();
    }    
}
```

this gives a compile error. if I replace `super.foo()` with `(B) super.foo()` it gives a runtime error. how to override this properly

Comment: Declaring a more specific return type (`B` instead of `A`) on an overriden method is legal. But `super.foo()` does _not_ return a `B`, so how are you expecting this cast to work?

Answer (score 1):

`super.foo()` returns an `A` instance, not a `B` instance, as you've seen. You'll need to construct the `B` instance you want to return by yourself:

```java
class B extends A {
    @Override
    B foo() {
        return new B();
    }    
}
```